# Why is this Python prime number print code not working?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple few lines to print prime numbers between 1000 - 10,000

Shouldn't this code work?  I'm taking i and dividing by 2 and saying if it does not equal remainder 0 then print the number as it would be prime.

```
for i in range(1000, 10000):
  if (i % 2) != 0:
    print(i)
```

Comment: A number not divisible by 2 is *odd*.  It may or may not be prime.

Comment: Did you really think that half of all numbers are prime?

Answer (score 0):

You attempt only prints all *odd* numbers from 1000 to 10000.

A naive `is_prime` function should check all numbers between 2 and sqrt(n) to see if n is evenly divisible by any of them.

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
  return all(n % i != 0 for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1))
```

Now, if you wish to print all primes between 1000 and 10000:

```
for i in range(1000, 10000):
  if is_prime(i): 
    print(i)
```

A better approach would be the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

```
def sieve(n):
  data = [True] * n
  for i in range(2, n):
    if data[i-1]:
      for j in range(2*i-1, n, i):
        data[j] = False
  return data
```

Now you can print all primes between 1000 and 10000 with a simple and very fast:

```
s = sieve(10000)

for i in range(1000, 10000):
  if s[i-1]: print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try too with a primality test:

with fermat theorem:

```py
for i in range(1000, 10000):
  if pow(2, i - 1, i) == 1:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

```py
for i in range(1000, 10000):
    for j in range(2, i):
        if i % j == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved with some elaboration.

Comment: Note also that your inner loop only needs to loop to the square root of `i`.